# angular is required validation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Only show the error or show has error required if field is clicked but right now on my current implementation when the setRequiredVlidations is called and the component loads the has required message is already showing as you can see on the image. It should only show if I click the input field or field is touch.

The user has option in the frontend if he select option 1 then validators is request if he click option 2 then validators is not request. My problem is when validator is set it is already showing before the user click the field , it should only show if user touch the field

```
if(option == 1) {
this.setRequiredVlidations();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTG9M.png)

```
initFormGroup() {
    this.modelForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [this.model.id || 0],
      emailAddress: [this.model.emailAddress, Validators.required],
      firstName: this.model.firstName,
      roleId: this.model.roleId,
      lastName: this.model.lastName,
      phoneNumber: this.model.phoneNumber,
      companyName: this.model.companyName,
      ssocredentials: [this.model.ssocredentials || ""],
      accountId: this.accountId,
      title: this.model.title,
      isSso: [this.model.isSso || "",]
    });
  }

  setRequiredVlidations() {
    this.modelForm.get('firstName').setValidators(Validators.required)
    this.modelForm.get('lastName').setValidators(Validators.required)
    this.modelForm.get('companyName').setValidators(Validators.required)
  }
```

#html

```
 <mat-card-content>
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
                        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 26px;">
                                <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="firstName">
                                <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('firstName').hasError('required')" >
                                    First name is required.
                                </mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 26px;">
                                <mat-label>Last name</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="lastName">
                                <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('lastName').hasError('required') && isExisting === false">
                                Last name is required.
                                </mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start">
                        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top:20px;">
                                <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="phoneNumber">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
                        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                <mat-label>Company Name</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="companyName">
                                <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('companyName').hasError('required') && isExisting === false">
                                    Company Name is required.
                                </mat-error>
                                
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 17px;">
                                <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="title">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </mat-card-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the input is touched or dirty:

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('companyName').hasError('required') && isExisting === false && (modelForm.get('companyName').touched || modelForm.get('companyName').dirty)">
   Company Name is required.
 </mat-error>
```

Comment: Hi Sir. Right now the is required message is not showing but the field is still red , is it a good practice to highlight the field as red before the user touch the field ? or we will remove the red color and only show if the field is touch ? Thanks.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/OC4UUpx , please check this one Sir , this is the current one

Comment: the message is already gone but the red line still remains

Comment: Not sure if it's related but in your setRequiredVlidations method, at the end, you should add `this.modelForm.updateValueAndValidity()` so the validation can have an effect. If you can create a demo on StackBlitz I can have a better look

Comment: I already have added the this.modelForm.updateValueAndValidity() but the form is still red

Comment: Hi Sir , is there a way to undo validations for example when I click the button I will undo specific validations like I only want to undo validations on first name?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `updateValueAndValidity` to the individual form controls and not the whole form. Something like this:

```
// Using forEach loop, you can reduce line of code as well. 

setRequiredVlidations() {
    const ctrls = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'companyName'];
    
    ctrls.forEach(eachCtrl => {
        const x = this.modelForm.get(eachCtrl);
        x.setValidators(Validators.required);
        x.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
}
```